# Laplace Transformations of a piecewise function

Tags: laplace-transform

This is a piece wise function. I'm not sure how to do piece wise functions in latex.

$$ f(t) =\begin{cases}\sin t &\text{if }  0 \le t < \pi,\\
 0&\text{if }  t \ge \pi.\end{cases} $$

So we want to take the Laplace transform of that equation.
So I get $L\{\sin t\} + L\{0\}$

Using the Laplace identities I get $L\{\sin t\} = \frac{1}{s^{2} + 1}$.

And $L\{0\} = 0$.

So for my answer I get $\frac{1}{s^{2} + 1} + 0$.

But the answer in the back of the book is $$\frac{1 + e^{-\pi s}}{s^{2} + 1}.$$

Where does the $$\frac{e^{- \pi s}}{s^{2} + 1}$$ come from?

Comment: Go back to the definition (and forget what you call L{sint}, which is not involved).

Comment: If you can't use the table all the time, how will you know when you can and can't use the identity table of Laplace transforms?

Comment: One "can't use the identity table of Laplace transforms" when the function one is dealing with is not in the list. Yours is NOT in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** You need to evaluate the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-st}\sin t dt$$

Do not use your tables in this case.

Comment: How do you know when you can and can't use the table?

Comment: If the table doesn't contain your problem, you can't use the table. Your problem is not the Laplace transform of a continuous sine wave starting at $t=0$.

Comment: Oh okay I see. Alright I am going to try it just using the definition.

Comment: @user71181 Naa, you *can* avoid doing the integration from scratch if your tables contain not only results for basic functions but also for some standrad transformations, see my answer. I assume that the purpose of the problem statement was rather to train your pattern recognition abilities to see how to combine the function in question using a few basic steps than to actually do the intagration. Then again, it does not hurt to do the integration as it is not *too* hard.

Answer (score 4):

> *Caveat:* One "can't use the identity table of Laplace transforms" when the function one is dealing with is not in the list. The function $f$ is NOT in the list. Hence the only option is to go back to the definition...

By definition, $Lf(s)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-st}f(t)\mathrm dt=\int_0^\pi\mathrm e^{-st}\sin(t)\mathrm dt$ for every complex number $s$ such that the integral converges (note the upper bound in the integral), hence
$Lf(s)=\frac1{2\mathrm i}(G(s-\mathrm i)-G(s+\mathrm i))$ with
$$
G(z)=\int_0^\pi\mathrm e^{-zt}\mathrm dt=\frac{1-\mathrm e^{-z\pi}}z,
$$
for every $z\ne0$. Thus, for every $s\ne\pm\mathrm i$,
$$
Lf(s)=\frac1{2\mathrm i}(1+\mathrm e^{-s\pi})\left(\frac1{s-\mathrm i}-\frac1{s+\mathrm i}\right)=\frac{1+\mathrm e^{-s\pi}}{1+s^2},
$$
and the remark that $G(0)=\pi$ yields
$$
Lf(s)=-s\frac{\pi}2,\quad s=\pm\mathrm i.
$$

Comment: It would be great if you could add a few words about this trick, because people learn that $s$ is a complex variable and looking at your elegant method might be confusing because it treats $s$ as a real-valued variable.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your input. The parameter $s$ **IS** real valued in Laplace transforms. The revised version mentions it.

Comment: Not when I learned about it: $s=\sigma + i\omega$. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition)

Comment: @Matt Ah. Well, see revised version.

Comment: Looks terrible :) I would have thought one might be able to come up with some argument based on analytic continuation. Anyway, thanks for making your answer precise and complete.

Comment: @Matt Indeed, I briefly suspected that you thought the "real parameter" formula was in fact valid for every complex parameter... which was a good reason to include the general case.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting to the core of the misunderstanding! My claim is that the original formula IS valid for complex $s$.

Comment: @Matt Your claim is right and I was wandering in the dark alleys of confusion... Thanks (and see revised version).

Comment: What a relieve, thanks! So why did that nice trick of yours work then (treating $s$ as real)? Must be something to do with analytic continuation.

Answer (score 1):

A piecewise combination of two functions is *not* the sum of these two functions.
Rather, your function is $\sin t$ plus a shifted $\sin t$.
More precisely, let
$$g(t)=\begin{cases}\sin t&\text{if }t\ge0,\\0&\text{if }t<0.\end{cases}$$
Then $f(t)=g(t)+g(t-\pi)$.
Do you how to obtain $L\{g(t-\pi)\}$ from $L\{g\}$ (assuming $g(t)=0$ for $t<0$)?