# How can we take the LaPlace transform of a piecewise function?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How can we take the LaPlace transform of a function, given piece-wise function notation?

For example, 
$f(t)=\begin{cases}
0 &\mbox{for } 0<t<2\\ t&\mbox{ for } 2<t
\end{cases}$

Frankly, I've read about step-functions but I can't find anything that really breaks down how these should be solved.

This question gives hints: [Laplace Transformations of a piecewise function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378022/laplace-transformations-of-a-piecewise-function)

But how do we REALLY come up with these integrals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the definition of the Laplace transform, and letting $f$ be the example function

$$f(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 < t < 2 \\ t & t \ge 2\end{array}\right.$$
we have

\begin{align*}
L\{f(t)\} &= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) dt \\
&= \int_0^2 e^{-st} f(t) dt + \int_2^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) dt \\
&= \int_0^2 e^{-st} \cdot 0 dt + \int_2^{\infty} e^{-st} t dt \\
&= \int_2^{\infty} t e^{-st} dt
\end{align*}

and the Laplace transform follows from just computing the integral. For any general piecewise function for which the integrals make sense, one just integrates the function on each separate interval of definition.

Comment: You know... I don't know why but nobody elses explanation seemed to have made sense. You just cleared up what I couldn't searching for 2 hours. :)

Comment: @VaughanHilts Glad I could be of help.

Comment: If I might be a bother, what is all this talk of unit step functions and where they might fit into the picture?

Comment: @VaughanHilts Step functions just give nice ways to write some piecewise functions (and have some nice interpretations in other senses); a function like yours can be written as $$f(t) = t u(t - 2)$$ where $u$ is the Heaviside step function.

Answer (score 0):

A more complex example, in the step-function form:
$$
f(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} \sin t & 0 < t < 2 \\ e^{-t} & t \ge 2\end{array}\right.
$$
Then $f(t) = \sin t + (e^{-t}-\sin t)u(t-2)$

Comment: See, I see a lot of these examples but nobody ever explains why they constructed it the way they did. Particularly, why is the unit function done the way it is? One can assume the - 2 comes from the interval, and infer the rest... but is this really understanding? If you could fill in a bit more details, a math student would super appreciate it. :)