# Using the Laplace translation on t axis to find $\sin(\pi t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

$$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
 \sin(\pi t) \,\,; 0 \leq t \leq 4 \\
\\
0 \,\,; t> 4
\end{cases}
$$

I am unsure of how to go about doing this. Seems to me the answer should be 
$$((1-e^{42})\pi)/s^2+\pi^2$$

I keep seeing answers online that tell me I am wrong but I do not know how to even go about solving this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This is very similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378022/laplace-transformations-of-a-piecewise-function

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general we are looking at:

$$\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\mathscr{L}_t\left[\text{y}\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}:=\int_0^\infty\text{y}\left(t\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t\tag1$$

In your case we get:

$$\text{F}\left(\text{s}\right)=\mathscr{L}_t\left[\text{f}\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}:=\int_0^\infty\text{f}\left(t\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t=\int_0^4\sin\left(\pi\cdot t\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t+\int_4^\infty0\cdot e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t$$

$$=\int_0^4\sin\left(\pi\cdot t\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t=\frac{\pi-\pi\cdot e^{-4\text{s}}}{\text{s}^2+\pi^2}\tag2$$